# Trigger event when selecting in a dropdown javascript eventlistener

Tags: javascript, list

I have this javascript function,

```
function listQ(){
 var e = document.getElementById("list");
 if(e.selectedIndex > 0){
  if("Blank Test" === e.selectedIndex){ alert("yo"); }
 }
}
```

My problem is how to trigger the function when selected the same value of dropdown list?

I tried this code,

```
document.getElementById("list").addEventListener("change",listQ);
```

And it must use an event listener.

Answer (score 11):

You can use the `onchange` method on your select element.

```
var changedText = document.getElementById('changed');
function listQ(){
    changedText.textContent = this.value;
}
document.getElementById("list").onchange = listQ;
```

For this HTML

```
<select id="list">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">Four</option>
</select>
<p>
  Your value <span id="changed"></span>
</p>
```

Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tboggia/4u5dmnzh/1/) forked from [Jonathan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2263949/jonathan), and here is MDN documentation for the [change](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change) event.

Comment: change `spam` to `span` lol

Comment: Thanks @Antoni!

Answer (score 2):

The line "Blank Test" isn't going to work because `e.selectedIndex` is going to be an index (a number).  You could use `e.options[e.selectedIndex].value`

Apart from that, just change the event listener to "click" instead of "change":

```
<select id="list">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="Blank Test">Four</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function listQ(){
    var e = document.getElementById("list");
    if(e.selectedIndex > 0){
      if("Blank Test" === e.options[e.selectedIndex].value){ alert("yo"); }
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("list").addEventListener("click",listQ);
</script>
```

Here's a Fiddle to demonstrate: https://jsfiddle.net/h81pcpm0/

Comment: Every time i click the dropdown, it triggers the event.

Comment: Is there no other way?

Comment: I'm sorry - I thought that was what you were looking for.  What is that you want?  Perhaps you want to only trigger when the value has not been changed?

Comment: I want oto have is, When a user select an option in to a dropdown list. If he/she chose the "Blank TesT" all data will be Deleted. If he/she chose others like, "Personal", it will change the Data. If he/she select Blank Test and input data, and Chose Blank Test again, the Dat awill be remove. but if he/she chose other, the data will be change.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved your problem here: https://jsfiddle.net/evL4cc5q/

```
var lastIndex = "";
function listQ(){
    var e = document.getElementById("list");
    if(e.selectedIndex > 0){
        if(e.selectedIndex != lastIndex) {
            if("Blank Test" === e.options[e.selectedIndex].value)
                alert("yo");
            lastIndex = e.selectedIndex;
        }
        else {
            lastIndex = "";
        }
     }
}
document.getElementById("list").addEventListener("click",listQ);
```

Comment: the lastIndex is equal to " ". so that it not execute the if(e.selectedIndex > 0) part.